# Finding downtime duration from server log table

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008-r2, query-performance

There is a table (SQL Server 2008 R2) that keeps the up/down log for multiple servers. The servers are pinged at regular intervals and their status (up or down) is written to this table. It has a structure like this:

```
CREATE TABLE StatusLog
(
  LogID INT PRIMARY KEY,
  ServerID INT,
  QueryDate DATETIME,
  ServerStatus VARCHAR(50)
)
```

Sample data

```
INSERT INTO StatusLog
VALUES
(1, '1724', '2016-04-16 09:28:00.000', 'up'),
(2, '1724', '2016-04-16 09:29:00.000', 'up'),
(3, '1724', '2016-04-16 09:30:00.000', 'down'),
(6, '1724', '2016-04-16 09:31:00.000', 'down'),
(8, '1724', '2016-04-16 09:32:00.000', 'down'),
(9, '1724', '2016-04-16 09:33:00.000', 'down'),
(17, '1724', '2016-04-16 09:33:40.000', 'up'),
(18, '1724', '2016-04-16 09:34:00.000', 'up')
```

I'm trying to find total downtime for a specific server for a given time period. 
In the data extract above, the status of the server with id 1724 becomes "down" at 09:30:00 and changes back to "up" at 09:33:40 which is a total downtime duration of 220 seconds.

My approach is:

1. For each "down block", find the "down" records and set their QueryDate as the down start time in a new column. This is fast.
2. In another new column, find the first "up" record after that down start time and set its QueryDate as the end of the down time. This is reasonably fast.
3. However, do this only for the first down record in down block and don't do it for other downs in a down block, otherwise you incorrectly calculate the same downtime multiple times. Now to do this, I need to to look at the row numbers and this is where things get messy and slow.
4. Finally, extract them from each other and you have down time for that block
5. Sum all down times to find the total down time.

I wrote the below script, however it is terribly slow (Each server has hundreds of thousands of log records)

```
DECLARE @StartDate DATE = '2016-04-01'
DECLARE @EndDate DATE = '2016-04-30'
DECLARE @ServerID INT = '1724' 

;WITH CTE_StatusLog AS 
(
SELECT LogID, QueryDate, ServerStatus, 
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY QueryDate) AS RN 
FROM StatusLog 
WHERE ServerID = @ServerID
    AND QueryDate BETWEEN @StartDate AND @EndDate
)

SELECT LogID, 
       QueryDate,
       ServerStatus,
       RN,
       DownStarted = CASE WHEN s1.ServerStatus = 'down' 
                          THEN s1.QueryDate END,
       DownEnded = (SELECT TOP 1 QueryDate 
                    FROM CTE_StatusLog AS s2 
                    WHERE s2.QueryDate > s1.QueryDate
                    AND s1.ServerStatus = 'down'
                    AND s2.ServerStatus = 'up'
                    AND (SELECT s3.ServerStatus 
                    FROM CTE_StatusLog AS s3 
                    WHERE s3.RN = s1.RN-1) <> 'down'
                ORDER BY s2.QueryDate),
       DownDuration = DATEDIFF(SECOND, 
                CASE WHEN s1.ServerStatus = 'down' 
                    THEN s1.QueryDate END, 
                (SELECT TOP 1 QueryDate 
                FROM CTE_StatusLog AS s2 
                WHERE s2.QueryDate > s1.QueryDate
                AND s1.ServerStatus = 'down'
                AND s2.ServerStatus = 'up'
                AND (SELECT s3.ServerStatus 
                    FROM CTE_StatusLog AS s3 
                    WHERE s3.RN = s1.RN-1) <> 'down'
                ORDER BY s2.QueryDate))
FROM CTE_StatusLog AS s1
WHERE QueryDate BETWEEN @StartDate AND @EndDate
ORDER BY s1.RN
```

The output:

```
LogID   QueryDate               ServerStatus   RN   DownStarted             DownEnded               DownDuration
1       2016-04-16 09:28:00.000 up             1    NULL                    NULL                    NULL
2       2016-04-16 09:29:00.000 up             2    NULL                    NULL                    NULL
3       2016-04-16 09:30:00.000 down           3    2016-04-16 09:30:00.000 2016-04-16 09:33:40.000 220
6       2016-04-16 09:31:00.000 down           4    2016-04-16 09:31:00.000 NULL                    NULL
8       2016-04-16 09:32:00.000 down           5    2016-04-16 09:32:00.000 NULL                    NULL
9       2016-04-16 09:33:00.000 down           6    2016-04-16 09:33:00.000 NULL                    NULL
17      2016-04-16 09:33:40.000 up             7    NULL                    NULL                    NULL
18      2016-04-16 09:34:00.000 up             8    NULL                    NULL                    NULL
```

How can I improve this script or is there a better way to calculate down time with respect to this table structure?

Comment: Hi Gani, Nowadays i am researching something which you asked years ago. Can you please share which scheduler job you have filling statuslog table? I mean how are you filling data to status table?

Comment: @microracle It was a Python script that used the API provided by the application that checked the up/down status. Basically, the script collected records from the API at certain intervals and batch-inserted them into the SQL Server.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would approach this by getting the next up time for each down record.  In SQL Server 2008, this uses `outer apply`:

```
select sl.*, slup.querydate as next_update,
       datediff(second, sl.querydate, slup.querydate) as down_in_seconds
from statuslog sl outer apply
     (select top 1 sl2.*
      from statuslog sl2
      where sl2.serverid = sl.serverid and
            sl2.querydate >= sl.querydate and
            sl2.serverstatus = 'up'
      order by sl2.querydate asc
     ) slup
where sl.serverstatus = 'down';
```

If you wanted a summary by downtimes, then I would use aggregation:

```
select servid, min(querydate) as down_date, next_update, 
       max(down_in_seconds)
from (select sl.*, slup.querydate as next_update,
             datediff(second, sl.querydate, slup.querydate) as down_in_seconds
      from statuslog sl outer apply
           (select top 1 sl2.*
            from statuslog sl2
            where sl2.serverid = sl.serverid and
                  sl2.querydate >= sl.querydate and
                  sl2.serverstatus = 'up'
            order by sl2.querydate asc
           ) slup
      where sl.serverstatus = 'down'
     ) slud
group by serverid, next_update;
```

Comment: Nice answer. I think you need to remove the group by down_in_seconds and instead aggregate that with a `MAX(...)`

Comment: @JamieF . . . Yes.  The next date can be in the `group by`, but the second change on each row.  Your are right.

Answer (score 1):

If you just need the total down time, you could figure out what each row represents: Let's say each down row represents the seconds of down time since last check of that server. Then SUM those rows:

```
DECLARE @StartDate DATE = '2016-04-01'
DECLARE @EndDate DATE = '2016-04-30'
DECLARE @ServerID INT = '1724'

SELECT
individualRows.ServerId,
individualRows.ServerStatus,
SUM(secondsInState) AS TotalTime
FROM
(Select
statusLog.ServerId,
statusLog.QueryDate,
statusLog.ServerStatus,
DateDiff(second, PreviousStatus.QueryDate, statusLog.QueryDate) as secondsInState
FROM
StatusLog
left outer join
StatusLog AS PreviousStatus
ON StatusLog.ServerId = PreviousStatus.ServerId
AND PreviousStatus.QueryDate < StatusLog.QueryDate
AND PreviousStatus.QueryDate = ( SELECT Max(QueryDate) FROM statusLog sl2 where sl2.ServerId= StatusLog.ServerId and sl2.QueryDate < StatusLog.QueryDate)
WHERE StatusLog.QueryDate > @StartDate
AND StatusLog.QueryDate < @EndDate
AND StatusLog.ServerId = @ServerID ) AS individualRows
GROUP BY
individualRows.ServerId,
individualRows.ServerStatus
```

If you really need the time for each outage, I might try a temp table with each row joined with the previous row as well as the previous row in the opposite state. Similar to your results. Then I would filter and aggregate that temp table.

My experience has been that temp tables are much faster than CTEs as soon as the table gets many rows of data.

Comment: You're right about the temp tables, I was going to go with them eventually but Gordon's approach was sufficient. Thank you.